# Understanding a question from the topic FUNCTIONS.

Tags: functions

I was trying to solve some problems about functions when I got stuck with this problem.

[image]

I am unable to understand this. First and foremost,
$$A=[1,2]$$
$$B=[3,4]$$

This seems to be a little daunting. Because, in the first step, they have written that,
$$f(A) = \{1\} $$

To be honest, I am seeing this for the first time (ie. Giving a set as the input and getting another set as the output). Maybe, they are trying to say that f(A) means f(a),where a is an element of A? Then why do they give its range in the form of a set?

You can see that in the second step, they have written that

$$f(A\cap\ B)$$ =$$f(\emptyset\ )$$=
$$\emptyset\ $$

How is this even possible? Empty set is not a member of the set of real numbers.
And the last two steps also. There, you can see that they have taken the inverse of f(A). Is this possible? What should I infer from this?

Perhaps I have some serious misunderstandings related to this. Could you be kind enough to resolve my confusion? (I mean, I have looked for a similar question in some books. But, it was hopeless.)

In short, I would like to have a detailed explanation of this question and its steps. Thank you first of all for spending your valuable time to help me understand this question.

Comment: You are correct.  If $S$ is a subset of the domain of a function $f$, then people often write $f(S)$ to denote $\{f(s)\,|\,s\in S\}$.  With that in mind, we do indeed have $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @lulu. So, I can say that $$f(A)$$ = {1} actually means that the elements of A correspond to the element 1. Then, How can I write its INVERSE? (since the same element corresponds to all the elements of A, it is not one one ) and how come it is (0,infinity)?

Comment: No.  You can say that $f(A)=\{f(a)\,|\,a\in A\}=\{1\}$.   Similarly, you can say that $f^{-1}(1)=\{x\in \mathbb R\,|\,f(x)=1\}=(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @lulu   one more doubt, please.  I was wondering about the elements of $$f^{-1}(1)$$ . Won't they be (1,1),(1,1.5),(1,1000) etc?. Doesn't that make it a relation, rather than a function?

Comment: I agree that $f^{-1}$ is not a function, at least not in the usual sense, because functions are required to take single values to single values.  When one writes, e.g., $f^{-1}(1)$, we mean $\{x\in \mathbb R\,|\,f(x)=1\}$.  Thus $f^{-1}$ of a single value might be an infinite set, as it is in this particular example.

Comment: @lulu. The inverse of the inverse of a function should be that function itself. It is not the case here.  I guess, they have given more importance to the input values for which 1 is the output.I believe they made a kind of informal approach there.Hey when you wrote that 'at least, not in the usual sense' are there any exceptions for the factors which decide whether a relation is function or not?Also, Could you reccomend some books where I can see similar situations? Anyway, thank you for the help!!

Comment: You can have functions which have sets as values, though that's not what they were thinking of here.   As you remark, $f^{-1}$ is not an inverse function in the sense one would like.  It is, nonetheless , useful.

Comment: Not entirely sure what sort of reference you want, but maybe try [this](https://smile.amazon.com/Functions-Graphs-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486425649/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=gelfand+functions&qid=1631805856&sr=8-1)